# Android - fill app with data frequently

Tags: android, xml

I have to create an app which shows a list of categories with products attached to each category.
The owner of the app uses this to inform customers about his products so there will be updates to the products every week.

Now I'm struggling how to create this app because there are a lot of options to do this, but I want to do it right of course.

So I was thinking about doing the following.
1. Creating a simple webapplication where the owner can manage his products and add/edit/delete them the way he wishes.
   When changes have been made he can push a button "publish" which creates an xml file.
2. When the app is started and there is an internet connection, the latest xml will be downloaded into the device and the app will list the categories, products from the xml.
   THe xml will be stored so that there are data to read when no internet connection is available.

Is this a good workaround? Or would maybe creating a webservice be a better idea?
But then the user should always be connected to the internet.

Some good advise would be welcome :)

Comment: I would change the XML to JSON. I think it's good. Just put a "refresh" button, not only when the app start to check the server, 'cause the user can turn on the internet conn after started your app. You can put more in your app, like the user can check all the 'owner' products and the user can select a list with interested products, then this list can be send to the server and the 'owner' maybe can know what's the customers most choices :D

Comment: Ok thanks, sending feedback about the product interaction to the "owner" is indeed a very good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

A internet connection should be available at any time, and if not it should not be the problem for you to cover.
But if you want to catch that case, you'll need (or could use) XML to persist the latest data to the device, in case your app has to start up without internet connection.

I would think about a RESTful WebService, since you can add features with ease once you have it runnuing (that could get tricky of course). Here is a tutorial you could use: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html